Plotting correctly the exponential, hyperbolic and inverted hyperbolic model curve in lattice
I am just trying to plot families of many models (whose names you can visualize as commented lines) on lattice graphs. However, I am not sure if the

EXPONENTIAL
INVERTED HYPERBOLIC
HYPERBOLIC

models are represented fine:
  xyplot(
  Petal.Width  ~ Petal.Length | Species,
  data = iris,
  panel = function(x, y, groups, ...) {
    panel.xyplot(x, y, ...)
    mod1 <- lm(y~x)
    mod2 <- lm(y~poly(x, 2))
    mod3 <- lm(y~poly(x, 3))
    mod4 <- nls(y ~ a * exp(-b * x), start = list(a = 1, b = 0.1), data = data.frame(x = x, y = y))  #exponential 
    mod5 <- nls(y ~ a / x, start = list(a = 1), data = data.frame(x = x, y = y)) #inverted hyperbolic  
    mod6 <- nls(y ~ a * x, start = list(a = 1), data = data.frame(x = x, y = y)) 
    #hyperbolic
    
    panel.abline(mod1, col='#0080ff')
    panel.curve(predict(mod2, newdata=data.frame(x=x)), col='purple', lwd=2)  
    panel.curve(predict(mod3, newdata=data.frame(x=x)), col='#ff00ff', lwd=2)
    panel.curve(predict(mod4, newdata=data.frame(x=x)), from = min(x), to = max(x), col = "red",lwd = 2)  
    panel.curve(predict(mod5, newdata=data.frame(x=x)), from = min(x), to = max(x), col = "green",lwd = 2)
    panel.curve(predict(mod6, newdata=data.frame(x=x)), from = min(x), to = max(x), col = "orange",lwd = 2)
    })

Could you correct if I am not plotting correct stuff? I am asking because in the first panel, I cannot get the graph.
Thanks

Looks like it should be correct.  The only thing I might suggest is you could have the nls() models fail a bit more gracefully by using try() and then only plotting the curves where nls() doesn't fail:
library(lattice)
xyplot(
  Petal.Width  ~ Petal.Length | Species,
  data = iris,
  panel = function(x, y, groups, ...) {
    panel.xyplot(x, y, ...)
    mod1 <- lm(y~x)
    mod2 <- lm(y~poly(x, 2))
    mod3 <- lm(y~poly(x, 3))
    mod4 <- try(nls(y ~ a * exp(-b * x), start = list(a = 1, b = 0.1), data = data.frame(x = x, y = y)))  #exponential 
    mod5 <- try(nls(y ~ a / x, start = list(a = 1), data = data.frame(x = x, y = y))) #inverted hyperbolic  
    mod6 <- try(nls(y ~ a * x, start = list(a = 1), data = data.frame(x = x, y = y))) 
    #hyperbolic
    
    panel.abline(mod1, col='#0080ff')
    panel.curve(predict(mod2, newdata=data.frame(x=x)), col='purple', lwd=2)  
    panel.curve(predict(mod3, newdata=data.frame(x=x)), col='#ff00ff', lwd=2)
    if(!inherits(mod4, "try-error"))panel.curve(predict(mod4, newdata=data.frame(x=x)), from = min(x), to = max(x), col = "red",lwd = 2)  
    if(!inherits(mod5, "try-error"))panel.curve(predict(mod5, newdata=data.frame(x=x)), from = min(x), to = max(x), col = "green",lwd = 2)
    if(!inherits(mod6, "try-error"))panel.curve(predict(mod6, newdata=data.frame(x=x)), from = min(x), to = max(x), col = "orange",lwd = 2)
    })


#> Error in nls(y ~ a * exp(-b * x), start = list(a = 1, b = 0.1), data = data.frame(x = x,  : 
#>   singular gradient

Created on 2024-04-05 with reprex v2.0.2

Ok. Thank you so much. But I could bot gry ehhh this way the model dose not fail. I mean, even though three is a try() check, it should be always the same model.

Not sure what you mean by "should always be the same model".   It will estimate the model for the points in that group.  The try() simply keeps the function from stopping when it encounters an error fitting one of the nls() models.

So what basically this try() function does is to coerce representation despite is not adequated to data, is it?

It does not plot the line ifor a particular model if that model results in an error, but it does point all other lines that do not result in an error.
